# Is there any way to get around the Exceptions of enhanced subscription filters of AppSync at the server side?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver, appsync-subscription

Exceptions as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/extensions.html
greatly impacts the capabilities of using enhanced filters for larger number of values for our usecase. for example, we would like to apply the 'containsAny' operator on an array containing more than 500 values. is there any way to get around these Limitations on the serverside?

***Exceptions***

**Note that there are several restrictions for using filters:**

In the filters object, there can be a maximum of five unique fieldName items per filter. This means that you can combine a maximum of five individual fieldName objects using AND logic.

**There can be a maximum of twenty values for the containsAny operator.**